# Cannot find $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{1}{\sin x-\cos x} \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am asked to find:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{1}{\sin x-\cos x} \, dx$$

I have tried:

$$A=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin^2 x-\cos^2 x} \, dx$$
$$A=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\sin x}{2\sin^2 x-1} \, dx + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\cos x}{1-2\cos^2 x} \, dx$$
$$u=\sin x$$
$$du=\cos x\,dx$$
$$v=\cos x$$
$$dv=-\sin x \,dx$$
$$A=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{du}{2u^2-1} \, dx + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{dv}{2v^2-1} \, dx$$

But I am unable to move forward.

Comment: "Dr. MV" 's answer is perhaps the quickest way to reduce this to known integrals.  Notice the trigonometric identity: $$A\cos x + B\sin x = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}\Big( \frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \cos x + \frac B{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \sin x \Big)$$ $$= \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \Big( \sin\varphi\cos x + \cos\varphi\sin x \Big) = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \sin(x+\varphi).$$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ However, "Dr. MV" 's way is not the only way.  I've posted a different one that starts where you leave off; see below. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Michael, I actually covered the partial fraction expansion approach too.  ;-)) - Mark

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\sin(x)-\cos(x)=\sqrt 2 \sin(x-\pi/4)$$

and integrate the cosecant function.

If you wish to proceed as in the OP, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1}{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}\,dx&=\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_1^{\sqrt 3/2}\frac{1}{2u^2-1}\,du+\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{2v^2-1}\,du\\\\
&=\frac12 \int_1^{\sqrt 3/2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 u-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 u+1}\right)\,du+\frac12 \int_0^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 v-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 v+1}\right)\,dv\\\\\
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: There is also a typo in your first identity.

Comment: @Nicolas Yep.  Edited!  Much appreciative.  - Mark

Comment: I found $$\frac{\ln{\tan{\frac{\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{4}}{2}}}}{\sqrt{2}} + C$$ Is that right?

Comment: That should be  $$\frac{\ln{\tan{\frac{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}{2}}}}{\sqrt{2}} + C$$

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works, there's always the "universal trig substitution" $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$, because then, due to trig identities, $\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, $\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, and (just in case) $\tan x=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$. That will take you to the realm of integrating rational functions, for which there's a standard (albeit lengthy) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{\sin x}{2\sin^2 x-1} \, dx = \int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{\sin x}{1 - 2\cos^2 x} \, dx & & \text{since }\sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x \\[15pt]
= {} & \int_1^{\sqrt 3/2} \frac{-dw}{1-2w^2} = \int_1^{\sqrt 3/2} \frac{-dw}{\left( 1 - w\sqrt 2\right)\left( 1 + w\sqrt2\right)} & & \text{and then use partial fractions.}
\end{align}